# Can't receive broadcast from bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I'm new to Bluetooth device development. My current project needs a function of using Bluetooth headset for online chatting. When user wants to start talking, he should press the call button for once(one button on the Bluetooth headset).
But it seems that the BroadcastReceiver object that I created couldn't receive any broadcasts when I press the buttons on the headset. The following is how I initialized the BroadcastReceiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT);
BroadcastReceiver event_Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){String cmd=intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_CMD);};
registerReceiver(event_Receiver, filter);
```

however, it is possible to receive connection state broadcast by setting the intentfilter with AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED.

I read several posts mentioning that the constant ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT doesn't work in Jelly Bean. Then do you guys know other ways to capture button pressing event from the Bluetooth headset?

**UPDATE:** I read the source code of the phone app from source.google.com. In package com.android.phone.BluetoothHandsfree, I found out this method: **broadcastVendorSpecificEventIntent()**. so the system does broadcast the AT command intent. but in my application I still cant receive this kind of broadcast, my guess is that the system receiver has consumed the broadcast which is sent by BLuetoothHandsfree object. anyone knows how to set higher priority than the system receiver in order to retrieve this kind of broadcast?

By the way, I've tried the method setPriority() in class IntentFilter by setting Integer.Max_Value, however, it didn't work.